# Spring MVC SimpleMappingExceptionResolver not resolving view when using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I've got a configuration that's very similar to the spring-petclinic application and it seems like `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` is working correctly and resolving to the view "error", but is not playing nicely with `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` to resolve that view:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'error' in servlet with name 'audit'
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1204)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
...
```

Here's the DEBUG log:

```
2014-11-13 14:58:24,249 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.foo.AuditGeneratorController.auditMessage(java.io.Writer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException]: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
2014-11-13 14:58:24,250 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.foo.AuditGeneratorController.auditMessage(java.io.Writer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException]: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
2014-11-13 14:58:24,250 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.foo.AuditGeneratorController.auditMessage(java.io.Writer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException]: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
2014-11-13 14:58:24,250 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.foo.AuditGeneratorController.auditMessage(java.io.Writer,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException]: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
2014-11-13 14:58:24,250 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving to default view 'error' for exception of type [com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException]
2014-11-13 14:58:24,250 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2014-11-13 14:58:24,251 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: ... (STACK TRACE SNIPPED)
2014-11-13 14:58:24,253 DEBUG org.springframework.web.accept.FixedContentNegotiationStrategy - Requested media types is text/html (based on default MediaType)
2014-11-13 14:58:24,253 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - Requested media types are [] based on Accept header types and producible media types [application/json, application/xml])
2014-11-13 14:58:24,255 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
2014-11-13 14:58:24,255 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver - No acceptable view found; returning null
2014-11-13 14:58:24,255 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'error' in servlet with name 'audit'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
```

Here's the view resolver config:

```
<!-- - The ContentNegotiatingViewResolver delegates to the InternalResourceViewResolver 
    and BeanNameViewResolver, - and uses the requested media type (determined 
    by the path extension) to pick a matching view. - When the media type is 
    'text/html', it will delegate to the InternalResourceViewResolver's JstlView, 
    - otherwise to the BeanNameViewResolver. -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager" />

    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <!-- Default viewClass: JSTL view (JSP with html output) -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'vets' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/vets.jsp' -->
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>

            <!-- Used here for 'xml' and 'atom' views -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Simple strategy: only path extension is taken into account -->
<bean id="cnManager"
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: if you read through the end of the stack trace line you'll see the problem is that it can't connect to the mongoDB.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm doing that intentionally to test the error handling.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it's apparent you are interested in Spring Error Handling. Please read the [very descriptive documentation on the subject](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) (`SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` section): All you have to do is register the [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html) with the default error view:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <!-- other params -->
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="yourDefaultViewForErrors"/>

</bean>
```